# User Manager object has no attribute create_superuser

Tags: python, django, django-models

Problem:
When using manage.py i’m unable to create a super user and it responds with the error  `AttributeError: 'UserManager' object has no attribute 'create_superuser’`. I then tried to manually import all of the necessary models and run it in a python shell and was met with the same roadblock.

Goal:
Properly create super user using inherited class of base manage

Code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager, Group

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, username):
        return self.get(username__iexact=username)

class User(AbstractUser):
    objects = UserManager()

    …
    …

    def __str__(self):
         return ’{}’.format(self.id)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super(FollowUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: In your `settings.py`, have you defined your custom user?? Something like `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app_name.User` ??

Comment: Yeah in the settings file it's registered as `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'`

Comment: note that `super(FollowUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` is wrong. Typo since your class is `User` not `FollowUser`?

Comment: Follow user is just in relation to another class within the same file. Just tried to include all the code that might have been helpful.

Comment: But calling the save method of the ancestor of another class when saving a `User` object can only lead to big trouble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[BaseUserManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager) does not have any method called `create_superuser`. Either you need to add it to the Manager Class like this(copy pasted from [github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L128)):

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a user with the given username, email, and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        username = self.model.normalize_username(username)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
```

Or, you can subclass your Manager from [UserManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager) Class.

Comment: The odd thing is that everyone else on the project had the ability to create a super user, any insight? This answer does help greatly though.

Comment: @Jacq what do you mean "everyone else on the project"?

Comment: Sorry, other coworkers. I've just been added on to this codebase and everyone working with the same code were able to create a super user but I wasn't able to do the same. It's just an oddity.

Comment: maybe the custom `UserManager` was created after they had created a super user. It should be inheriting from the standard django `UserManager` anyway, because missing the `create_user()` method might also lead to issues when registering new users.

Comment: maybe they just used the `django shell` to create super users.